# How to uninstall MariaDB 5.5 completely (including configurations) from CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, centos-7, mariadb

I tried command

```
yum remove mariadb mariadb-server
```

It removed the client but failed to remove the server.

```
error reading information on service mysql: No such file or directory
error: %preun(MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64
error: MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64: erase failed
Erasing    : MariaDB-client-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        1/2 
Verifying  : MariaDB-client-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        1/2 
Verifying  : MariaDB-server-5.5.41-1.el7.centos.x86_64                                                                                        2/2 

Removed:
MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:5.5.41-1.el7.centos                                                                                                       

Failed:
MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:5.5.41-1.el7.centos
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled MariaDB and then uninstalled using **rmp** not yum. Below are the steps I performed-

**Downloaded the required RPMs**

```
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-client.rpm
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-common.rpm
wget http://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-5.5.41/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-5.5.41-centos7_0-x86_64-server.rpm
```

**Install it again**

```
rpm -ivh MariaDB-5.5.41-*.rpm
```

**Erase packages**

```
rpm -e `rpm -qa | grep MariaDB` --noscripts
```

**Remove the config files**

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm /etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: rm -rf /var/lib/mysql and rm /etc/my.cnf what this 2 actually do? after i follow a few guide to get mariadb uninstall, my database data is gone too

Comment: the file **/etc/my.cnf** is the configuration file and the data files are contained in **/var/lib/mysql**. So, if you remove **/var/lib/mysql** then your data will be removed too.
Try to open the file /etc/my.cnf with a text editor and look for datadir, you'll see something like **datadir = /var/lib/mysql**
The path to your data files.